# "no store nearby" or "no nearby store"

Tags: adverbs, adjectives

Would you tell me the reason why native speakers often say *store nearby* instead of *nearby store*?

> There is no store **nearby**.
>   There is no **nearby** store.

One of my friends gave me this answer:

> I would naturally use "There is no store nearby / There is no nearby store" in this sort of context:
>
> > A: Did you go to the nearby store?
> >     B: There is no nearby store.
>
> Speaker A is presupposing that there is a nearby store.
>   Speaker B is denying that presupposition.

But I don't understand yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two sentences have slightly different grammatical structure.  "Nearby" can be either an adjective or an adverb.  In the first sentence, "nearby" is adverb, modifying the verb "is".  In the second sentence, "nearby" is an adjective describing the store.  This changes the meaning of the two slightly.  Saying "nearby store" like  in the second sentence makes the sentence about that store that is nearby, rather than an undescribed store, like in the first sentence.